# separate text in a column by a delimiter (|), and then stack all separated values into a single column without duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, delimiter

I have a data report that is entered into SQL Server with job cards bunched together.
I am creating a report off this SQL table that looks at an excel report and checks which job cards are missing.
So far I worked out a manual method of fixing the data from the sql table to unbunch the job cards using text to columns,  and then stacking the columns to create one gigantic column,  but it would be nice to have a method that automated it in Sql server.
Example:
[each line in column 1 is a row]

```
Column 1
A437|Bb7772|d763ch
D444r7|Z71|
A37|Bc7772|766ch
```

Needs to look like this:

```
Column 1
A437
Bb7772
d763ch
D444r7
Z71
A37
Bc7772
766ch
```

I would also remove all,  if any,  duplicates once the new column is created.

Sorry for the trouble,  but I honestly don't even know where to begin with splitting the column from the start in SQL.
I imagine I can use the UNION all function to stack the values into a new column.

Oh and more complications, the amount of job cards grouped is variable (could be just two bunched together,  could be as many as 6, could be just a single job card).

I am in a corner or I wouldn't have even bothered asking. Yea, my company's method of organization of job cards sucked.

Comment: This is probably something I would do outside of SQL with a scripting language like Python.

Comment: I agree with Michael, it's probably best to do it outside of Sql, or using a CLR function.

Answer (score 1):

From [my DBA post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72292/splitting-a-csv-column-from-select-query-into-multiple-columns) on the same topic:

Making use of Jeff Moden's Tally-Ho! CSV splitter from [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
WITH E1(N) AS (
           SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
           SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
           SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
       ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
            SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() 
                                                        OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
        ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just
                     -- once for each delimiter)
            SELECT 1 UNION ALL
            SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
        ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
            SELECT s.N1,
                   ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
            FROM cteStart s
        )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final
     -- element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
go
```

We can code the solution as an apply against Jeff's function and a pivot like so:

```
with data as (
    select Code,Location,Quantity,Store from ( values
        ('L698-W-EA',          NULL,                                      2, 'A')
       ,('L82009-EA',          'A1K2, A1N2, C4Y3, CBP2',                  2, 'A')
       ,('L80401-A-EA',        'A1S2, SHIP, R2F1, CBP5, BRP, BRP1-20',    17,'A')
       ,('CWD2132W-BOX-25PK',  'A-AISLE',                                 1, 'M')
       ,('GM22660003-EA',      'B1K2',                                    1, 'M')
    )data(Code,Location,Quantity,Store)
)
,shredded as (
    select Code,Location,Quantity,Store,t.*
    from data
    cross apply [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K](data.Location,',') as t
)
select 
    pvt.Code,pvt.Quantity,pvt.Store
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[1],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc1
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[2],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc2
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[3],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc3
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[4],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc4
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[5],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc5 
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[6],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc6
from shredded
pivot (max(Item) for ItemNumber in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])) pvt;
;
go
```

yielding this:

```
Code              Quantity    Store Loc1     Loc2     Loc3     Loc4     Loc5     Loc6
----------------- ----------- ----- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------
L698-W-EA         2           A                                                   
L82009-EA         2           A     A1K2      A1N2     C4Y3     CBP2              
L80401-A-EA       17          A     A1S2      SHIP     R2F1     CBP5     BRP      BRP1-20
CWD2132W-BOX-25PK 1           M     A-AISLE                                       
GM22660003-EA     1           M     B1K2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Function

```
 CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split](@text varchar(8000), @delimiter varchar(20))
    RETURNS @Strings TABLE
    (   
      position int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
      value varchar(8000)  
    )
    AS
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @index int
    SET @index = -1

    WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0)
      BEGIN 
        SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text) 
        IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0) 
          BEGIN  
            INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (@text)
              BREAK 
          END 
        IF (@index > 1) 
          BEGIN  
            INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (LEFT(@text, @index - 1))  
            SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index)) 
          END 
        ELSE
          SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))
        END
      RETURN
    END
```

Query

```
select value from fn_split( (select stuff(( select '|'+Column1 from table1 for xml path('')),1,1,'')) ,'|')
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many string splitting functions for Sql Server.
Most of them perform better when you have a short list of small strings.
You can read [this article](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) for a performance test between some of the leading solutions.

For this example, I'll go with the  Jeff Moden's splitter function from that article, but you should choose whatever function best suited for your needs.

```
--  Create the sample data
CREATE TABLE MyTable (Column1 varchar(max))
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES 
('A437|Bb7772|d763ch'),
('D444r7|Z71|'),
('A37|Bc7772|766ch')

-- Create the split function
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings
(
   @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
  WITH E1(N)        AS ( SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
       E2(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b),
       E4(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b),
       E42(N)       AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E2 b),
       cteTally(N)  AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@List,1))) 
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E42),
       cteStart(N1) AS (SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t
                         WHERE (SUBSTRING(@List,t.N,1) = @Delimiter OR t.N = 0))
  SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@List, s.N1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000))
    FROM cteStart s;
```

And now, for the actual solution:

```
DECLARE @AllValues varchar(max)

-- Concatenate all the values in Column1 to a single string. 
-- the replace function is to prevent a double delimiter in case of the value of any row begins or ends with the delimiter
SELECT @AllValues = REPLACE(STUFF((
   SELECT '|'+ Column1
   FROM MyTable 
   FOR XML PATH('')
 ), 1, 1, ''), '||', '|')

-- These are the distinct values:
SELECT DISTINCT Item
FROM dbo.SplitStrings(@AllValues, '|')
```

Now, Assuming this table have only one column, you can do this:

```
-- get the values in the column
SELECT @AllValues = REPLACE(STUFF((
   SELECT '|'+ Column1
   FROM MyTable 
   FOR XML PATH('')
 ), 1, 1, ''), '||', '|')

-- delete all rows from the table
TRUNCATE TABLE MyTable 

-- insert new values
INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT DISTINCT Item
FROM dbo.SplitStrings(@AllValues, '|')
```

[Read here](http://www.essentialsql.com/what-is-the-difference-between-truncate-and-delete-in-sql-server/) to find out why I've chosen truncate table instead of delete

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @t table(id int identity(1,1), name varchar(100))
INSERT @t VALUES
('A437|Bb7772|d763ch'),
('D444r7|Z71'),
('A37|Bc7772|766ch')

;WITH Value AS
(
     SELECT row_number() over(order by id) rn,t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)') name
     FROM (
         SELECT id, x = CAST('<t>' + 
               REPLACE(name, '|', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
         FROM @t
     ) a
     CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/t') t(c)
)
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM Value
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `Column1` is always like `'%|%|%'` use this query:

```
SELECT part 
FROM (
    SELECT LEFT(column1, CHARINDEX('|', column1, 0) - 1) part
    FROM t
    UNION 
    SELECT SUBSTRING(column1, CHARINDEX('|', column1, 0) + 1, CHARINDEX('|', column1, CHARINDEX('|', column1, 0) + 1) - CHARINDEX('|', column1, 0) - 1)
    FROM t
    UNION 
    SELECT RIGHT(column1, CHARINDEX('|', REVERSE(column1), 0) - 1)
    FROM t) parts
WHERE 
    part <> ''
```

Comment: Note that the OP's example had different number of values between delimiters, and also wrote specifically "the amount of job cards grouped is variable (could be just two bunched together, could be as many as 6, could be just a single job card)."

Comment: Thanks all for your effort on this as well as all the information and resources to help me along further.  This is much appreciated. I will try out the various solutions and will report back if hopefully the results are successful